What happens if constant appeared in seperating variables of cylindrical Laplace's equation is negative?
I'm trying to solve a Dirichlet problem of Laplace's equation in a region with cylindrical symmetry, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\left(\rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial\rho}\right)+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z^2}=0,&\rho<a,0<z<h,\\
u|_{\rho=a}=0,&0\le z\le h,\\
u|_{z=0}=0,&\rho\le a,\\
u|_{z=h}=A,&\rho\le a.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here $A$ is a constant, $\rho\ge0$. Using variable-seperation method, we want to look for solutions of the form
$$
u(\rho,z)=R(\rho)Z(z)
$$
Substituting this into the above equation, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\rho}(\rho R''+R')Z+RZ''=0
$$
Divide both sides by $RZ$, we get
$$
-\frac{\rho R''+R'}{\rho R}=\frac{Z''}{Z}
$$
Since lhs and rhs are about different variable, they must be equal to a constant $\mu$.
Here is my question: I have seen in most cases we suppose $\mu>0$, then we solve the equation
$$
Z''-\mu Z=0
$$
to get
$$
Z(z)=C(e^{\sqrt{\mu}z}-e^{-\sqrt{\mu}z})
$$
where $C$ is a constant related to $A$. But on the other hand, in handout I find $\mu<0$ can be accepted. Then why we pay such attention to the case $\mu>0$ but almost neglect $\mu<0$? Is it just for simplicity or something else?
Moreover, I can't give a physical explain about explosion(when $\mu>0$) or oscillation(when $\mu<0$) of $Z$ when $\rho=0,A>0,|z|\rightarrow\infty$. I know solutions of Laplace's equation means electric potential, thus I regard $Z$ as electric potential. But we always suppose that electric potential decays when $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, it neither explodes nor oscillates, which contradicts to what happened on $Z$. Why?
A more precise description: If the equation is written under Cartesian coordinates, we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)\\
f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=-A\cdot\chi_{\{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}\le a\}\cap\{x_3=h\}}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where
$$
\chi_{E}=\begin{cases}
1,&x\in E\\
0,&x\notin E
\end{cases}
$$
then to solve the original equation is to solve the Poisson's equation above. I know there will exist a sequence of compact supported smooth function $\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ s.t. $f_k$ uniformly converse to $f$. Now consider equation
$$
-\Delta u=f_k
$$
whose solution is denoted as $u^{(k)}$, then by taking convolution with fundamental solution of Laplace's equation $\Phi$ we get
$$
u^{(k)}(x)=(\Phi*f_k)(x)=C\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{f_k(x-y)}{|y|}dy
$$
where $C$ is a constant, $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Since $\text{supp}f_k$ is compact and $f_k$ is uniformly bounded, we can assume that
$$
\text{supp}f_k\subset E,\ |f_k|\le M,\ k=1,2,\cdots
$$
where $E$ is a bounded set and $M<\infty$ is a constant. Then
$$
|u^{(k)}(x)|\le C\int_{x+E}\frac{Mdy}{y}\rightarrow0,\ |x|\rightarrow\infty
$$
Since $f_k$ converges to $f$, I think $u^{(k)}$ should converge to $u$, thus $\lim\limits_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}|u(x)|=0$. But back to the original equation, if we set $\rho=0$ and let $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, there may not be $|Z|\rightarrow0$, thus we can't get $|u(0,z)|=|R(0)||Z(z)|\rightarrow0$. Is this a contradiction? I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. For some problems, you can tell from context which is more plausible, $Z\propto e^{\sqrt{\mu}z}-e^{-\sqrt{\mu}z}$ with $\mu>0$. $Z\propto\sin(\sqrt{-\mu}z)$ with $\mu<0$ or $Z\propto z$ with $\mu=0$. (I'm assuming you want solutions for which $Z=0$ at $z=0$.)

Thank you for answering! I wander if you mean that which $\mu$ I should choose depends on the context of the equation? Equation itself can't tell which one is more plausible?

I'm more thinking of how you expect $Z$ to behave as $z\to\infty$. Will it exponentially explode, oscillate, or grow linearly? That's really more of a physical question. (The behaviour of $R$, rather than $Z$, may provide a similar clue.)

I expect $Z$ tends to be a constant when $z\rightarrow\infty$. In my thought the context of this equation is to solve electric potential $u$. Boundary condition(BC for short) is satisfied by putting electric charge(EC for short) in space, this EC distribution has the potential which is required by BC. I think there will be a bounded region $E$ s.t. EC distribution inside $E$ is sufficient to give BC. When $|z|\rightarrow\infty$, since $E$ is bounded, difference caused by how EC distribute in $E$ can be neglected. Then I treat EC as a point charge, whose potential at infinity should be constant

Maybe you couldn't be looking at $Z(0)=0$ solutions, then.

I've tried to redescribe my question, in which I explained why I think $Z$ may at least tend to a constant mathematically.

Your $f$ in the second formulation does nothing, because it is everywhere finite and only nonzero on a null set. In particular it does not implement the $z=h$ BC in the original formulation. You need a Dirac delta forcing to achieve that.

Anyway, you have to pin down what BCs you're talking about. For one sign of the eigenvalue, you kill the singularity at the axis for one BC and then the eigenvalue and eigenfunction are determined by the requirement that $J_0$ be evaluated at one of its zeros. For the other sign of the eigenvalue, you kill the singularity at the axis for one BC, but now $I_0$ has no real zeros, so that rules out the possibility of that sign for the eigenvalue. But this case becomes possible with a different BC.

I got it! $f$ shouldn't be constant but explode on $z=h$, then $|f_k|\le M$ actually isn't right, which means we can't have $|u|\rightarrow0$. But can you tell more about "kill the singularity at the axis for one BC"? I don't catch why we can rules out one possibility.

Both signs of the eigenvalue produce a logarithmic singularity at $\rho=0$ if one of the coefficients is nonzero. That's nonphysical, so you set that coefficient to zero. Then only one sign of the eigenvalue produces radial eigenfunctions with real zeros.

So we use equation about $R$ but not $Z$ to finally determine which sign $\mu$ should have?

For the case when $u$ vanishes on the curved edge of the cylinder, yes.

I got it. Thank you very much!
